# Php tag giving me error

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie with PHP and I have been searching for ways to debug this but I can't find out what's wrong.

My index.php page works but when I do view source, I can view the whole exact code of the page, it's not incripted or protected. So I thought well, this is what PHP is for and this website is hosted on a PHP-suporting server so I tried adding the PHP tags `<?php` and `?>` but this gives me a parse error, no matter what.

I went down to the most simple code of the page and removed almost everything yet it's still giving me error.

Please look at my php page code below. Again, adding the `<?php` tag gives me a parse error.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div align="Center">
<?php
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot put HTML inside PHP like this. PHP is often used to generate HTML *dynamically*. You cannot protected/hide your HTML with PHP, since the browser has to be able to read the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use HTML inside PHP like this. HTML is not a part of PHP syntax.

> My index.php page works but when I do view source, I can view the whole exact code of the page, it's not incripted or protected. So I thought well, this is what php is for

PHP is not intended, nor can it be used, to hide HTML source code from the browser. The browser needs this code to be able to render the webpage. PHP is a language in which you can program a great deal of things. Popular uses are pulling data from databases and presenting information based on dynamically generated stuff. However, mostly the output in a web application context is still pure (x)HTML code. The browser needs this to display stuff - it's all it understands.

Comment: Thanks Thom! Another pointer absorbed and gained better understanding of PHP. My new client asked me to learn PHP and MySQL so I'm still starting with this.:)

Answer (score -1):

you do not need php code if your code is just html. html will work on a php server as filename.html or filename.php you only need the .php extention if you intend on writing php code.

you can not protect what you want the user to see. you can protect the php code but not the html or the intended output from php.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div align="Center">
<?php
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">';
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div align="Center">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you read the question and understand what the OP *actually* wants?

Comment: I'm gonna up him up for this. He sent a different answer and it may be against the rules but I learned something from this. All of the replies gave me a better understanding of PHP. I was told before that PHP is the ASP for Javascript version and that PHP and ASP hides important part of the codes. I thought they hide the whole thing :p